# Instantiating a class and calling method in lambda foreach

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach

Is it possible to do this in a ForEach lambda expression?

```
reports.ForEach(x => new PublishReport(x)
      PublishReport.PublishReports());
```

What I'm trying to do is instantiate the PublishReport (bare with the class and method name) class passing a report object and then calling the PublishReports method of the PublishReport class.

The work around I have done is:

```
reports.ForEach(x => CallPublishReports(x));

private void CallPublishReport(Report report)
{
    PublishReport publishReport = new PublishReport(report);
    publishReport.PublishReports();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a static method instead? Then you could just call ``PublishReport.PublishReports(x)``

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Didn't think of that. Will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking for looks something like this:

```
reports.ForEach(x => (new PublishReport(x)).PublishReport());
```

Or

```
reports.ForEach(x => {
    var report = new PublishReport(x);
    report.PublishReports();
});
```

You can replace `ForEach`, with `Select`, as well, as the former only exists in PLINQ afaik.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by first using `Select` to create the instances then `ForEach` over them like this:

```
reports
    .Select(r => new PublishReport(r))
    .ForEach(pr => pr.PublishReports());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give the lambda a body:

```
reports.ForEach(x => 
{
    PublishReport publishReport = new PublishReport(x);
    publishReport.PublishReports();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! When instantiating, the PublishReport class in the code above,should that be x?